# Simple integer regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have `ValidationRegularExpression="[0-9]"` which only allows a single character. How do I make it allow between (and including) 1 and 7 digits? I tried `[0-9]{1-7}` but it didn't work.

Comment: +1. Although it's a simple question, you stated the question clearly, defined your expected result and told us what you had already tried. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got the syntax almost correct: `[0-9]{1,7}`.

You can make your solution a bit more elegant (and culture-sensitive) by replacing `[0-9]` with the generic character group "decimal digit": `\d` (remember that other languages might use different characters for digits than 0-9).

And here's the documentation for future reference:

- [.NET Framework Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx)

Comment: +1 and my almost identical answer deleted. You were *very* quick off the mark there. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid leading zeros, you can use this:

```
^(?!0\d)\d{1,7}$
```

The first part is a negative lookahead assertion, that checks if there is a 0 followed by a number in the string. If so no match.

Check online here: http://regexr.com?2thtr