# How to check if a string is a valid integer?

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I have:

```
 op1 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
 op2 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
```

However, I want to check first whether the text fields' values can be assigned to integer variables. How do I do that?

I've been going through this for a long time, so, if this was already asked here, forgive me

Comment: `if (op1 == 0)`? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: That's why I said it's hard to explain. I want to check if I can assign a value to a variable

Comment: Wait, are you saying that `if((int i = 0) == true)` is valid C code?!

Comment: If it's not a valid integer you'll get an exception. If you don't get the exception, you can assign it.

Comment: You can, if you couldn't, the compiler would complain. (potential exception: autoboxing and null values)

Comment: Hi @user3314478, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I have edited your question according to your comment on one of the answers. If my edit changed the intent of your question, please feel free to [edit] further, or go into the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21803908/revisions) and roll back the edit. Do however note that as it stands, this question is very likely to be closed as a duplicate of some other question on the site.

Comment: See [5660595] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660595/simple-integer-regular-expression)

Comment: @JonathanRosenne Um, no. That's ASP.NET, this is Java. It's also about regular expressions, which I definitely don't think the OP here needs. Remember the old adage; you have a problem, and think "I know, I'll use regular expressions" - now you have two problems. While regexes are useful in certain scenarios, they have serious drawbacks as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't do `if (int i = 0)`, because assignment returns the assigned value (in this case `0`) and `if` expects an expression that evaluates either to `true`, or `false`.

On the other hand, if your goal is to check, whether `jTextField.getText()` returns a numeric value, that can be parsed to `int`, you can attempt to do the parsing and if the value is not suitable, `NumberFormatException` will be raised, to let you know.

```
try {
    op1 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Wrong number");
    op1 = 0;
}
```

Comment: The use of an exception as a branching mechanism is discouraged. If the input is likely to be malformed, an explicit validity check should be performed rather than exception catching.

Comment: Typo: `NumericFormatException` should be `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me. Simply to identify whether a String is a primitive or a number.

```html
private boolean isPrimitive(String value){
        boolean status=true;
        if(value.length()<1)
            return false;
        for(int i = 0;i<value.length();i++){
            char c=value.charAt(i);
            if(Character.isDigit(c) || c=='.'){
                
            }else{
                status=false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return status;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

parseInt throws NumberFormatException if it cannot convert the String to an int. So you should surround the parseInt calls with a try catch block and catch that exception.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have to decide to check if a given string is a valid integer or you simply assume a given string is a valid integer and an exception can occur at parsing.

Comment: I want to check if the string is a valid integer

Comment: Then please search SO for yourself, this topic is as old as Java.

Comment: You could have aswered the question instead of complaining .-.

Comment: Part of asking a question in a forum is thinking about the abstract problem behind the question - and if you're not able to type in "java check string integer" in the search box, sorry.